How to create an array of objects in google script using object.map
I am trying to create an array of objects derived from a list of users and have the following line of code:
var usersEmail=group.map((user)=>{eMail : user.email, rOle : user.role});
the ':' in 'rOle : user.role' causes an error of unexpected ':' when I try to save the code.  If I use this code:
var usersEmail=group.map((user)=>[user.email, user.role]);

I create an array of 2 element array's, which works but is not as nice as I would like.  My final attempt was this:
var usersEmail=group.map((user)=>[{eMail : user.email, rOle : user.role}]);

which creates an array of single element arrays each of which contain the correct object.  I feel that what I want to do is entirely possible, but I just don't have the right structure to do so.
Grateful for any help.

Apologies, I found the solution.  I simply needed to bracket the object creation clause with ( ) so that it becomes: var usersEmail=group.map((user)=>({eMail : user.email, rOle : user.role}));

=> {} is a block. To return an object from a implicitly returned arrow function use => ({})

I think this is what you are looking for :
var usersEmail = group.map((user)=> ({eMail : user.email, rOle : user.role}));

they are needed here because you are using an inline (anonymous) function, so you need something to show that this is indeed an object and not a function.
You could also do it this way :
 var usersEmail = group.map((user)=> {
    return {eMail : user.email, rOle : user.role};
 });

